# How to create and read HTML elements with same ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a for-loop that creates a list. Each item on the list has a hidden input and function as below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="network-id" name="network_id" value="1">
<button type="button" onclick="transfer(someId);"></button>
```

I'm using my JS code to read the hidden input in `transfer` function.

```
networkId = $("#network-id").val();
```

But since each element ID is the same, it only reads the first `"network-id"` element on the list.

What is the best way to read each element?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique.  If you have more than one with the same name, JS will only grab the last one.  You need to figure out a way to give these elements a unique ID as you build them in your loop

Answer (score 1):

Use a [class name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) or just take the [previous element sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling) of each button.

```js
function transfer(button){
  console.log(button.previousElementSibling.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="foo" value="1">
<button type="button" onclick="transfer(this);">One</button> 

<input type="hidden" class="foo" value="2">
<button type="button" onclick="transfer(this);">Two</button> 

<input type="hidden" class="foo" value="3">
<button type="button" onclick="transfer(this);">Three</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers.

Id's should be unique, so you should use something else to identify fields/elements. I would suggest [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Using `data-attributes` you don't even need a hidden input field to store a value. A value can be assigned directly to the button.

With that in mind, here is a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to handle buttons using [event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and to read out the value from the buttons' `data-attribute`.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

createSomeButtons();

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.bttnid) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`transfer value: ${evt.target.dataset.value}`);
  }
}

function createSomeButtons() {
  const bttns = [...Array(10)].map( (_, i) => {
    const bttn = document.createElement(`button`);
    bttn.dataset.bttnid = `${i + 1}`;
    bttn.dataset.value = `bttn ${i + 1}`;
    bttn.textContent = `transfer ${i + 1}`;
    return bttn.outerHTML; } );
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, bttns.join(`<br>`));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs should be unique. You can adjust your code so that it gives each element the same class instead or give each element a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Function and add ++ in every time after that when loop run it run with the function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).